# Do a single column sum of values in BIRT

Tags: birt

I have a problem here.

I am working on an invoice template using BIRT. I have a table column qty, unit price and amount (unit price * qty). At the table footer, I want to compute the total amount like how excel does its column sum of values. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, Insert a Data element in a grid from a palete where you want the sum.
Then right click on that data element in your report and click on 'Change data Column'
Select Dataset which have columns 'qty' and 'unit cost' etc. then click on Add Aggregation in this select datatype float and function sum and add expression in which set datarow(name of column) of which you want sum.

Answer (score 11):

In the table footer, add a Data. Then, in Data Binding, on Expression:

`Total.sum(dataSetRow["yourRow"])`

Answer (score 0):

Most reporting tools allow you to do that from the toolbar.

Select the amount column in your report and look for the Total/sum/aggregate toolbar icon, and it should do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Dynamic Text` element.

And then select the Row you want to sum up in the Expression Builder:

[image: Sum screenshot]